# Unable to detect monitor webcam in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, webcam

I am using ubuntu 10.04 on a desktop PC. I have connected my 17" Dell LCD monitor with webcam (using  the monitor's USB cable).

Ubuntu does not detect the webcam at all (I tried Skype and Cheese, both say no device found). 
(The monitor webcam works fine in Windows).

How do I make the webcam work?

Answer (score 4):

I honestly have no clue what *kind* of webcam is built into your monitor... but try doing a lsusb in a console to get the USB IDs of the device, and use that to locate drivers.  It's possible that the manufacturer doesn't have any sort of linux-based driver.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

`$ lsusb
....
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 05a9:2643 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. Monitor Webcam
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0424:2512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Any clue how to I make it work?

Comment: It looks like your webcam doesn't have built-in support in ubuntu yet.  There is a linux-driver you can use, but I have no clue how stable or reliable it is... http://www.rastageeks.org/downloads/ov51x-jpeg/